# Open webpage after gwtRun - Batch File

Tags: batch-file

```
call gradlew -g ./ build
call gradlew -g ./ gwtRun
start http://localhost:8080
```

I have this simple batch file. While this should work, the `gwtRun` stays stuck at 83% (while correctly working if I manually open the webpage) it doesn't callback the batch file and subsequently it never opens the start command. Is there anyway so that the start is still performed?

Thanks!

Comment: The web page will not open until the previous command finishes executing and returns control back to the batch file.

Comment: What do you expect `http://localhost:8080` to do? I think you need to reference an actual browser program in there somewhere.